# Python list.remove() not working

Tags: python, regex, list

I am including a python file commands.py using
    import commands

The file is as follows:

```
import datetime

def what_time_is_it():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    return(str(today))

def list_commands():
    all_commands = ('list_commands', 'what time is it')
    return(all_commands)
```

I would like the main script to list the functions in commands.py, so I'm using `dir(commands)` which gives the output:

`['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'datetime', 'list_commands', 'what_time_is_it']`

I then tried to use regular expressions to remove the items that include '__' as follows:

```
commands_list = dir(commands)
for com in commands_list:
   if re.match('__.+__', com):
      commands_list.remove(com)
   else:
      pass
```

This doesn't work. If I try to do it without the for loop or the regular expressions, it claims that the entry (which I had just copied and pasted from print(list) is not in the list.

As a secondary question, can I get dir to only list the functions, rather than 'datetime' as well?

Comment: No need for `regex` I don't think. `new_lst = [item for item in lst if '__' not in item]`

Comment: I would use a list comprehension here.  `[i for i in dir(commands) if not (i.startswith('__') and i.endswith('__'))]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't modify a list while you're iterating it, use a list comprehension instead:

```
commands_list = dir(commands)
commands_list = [com for com in commands_list if not re.match('__.+__', com)]
```

As your second question, you can use `callable` to check if a variable is callable or not.

Comment: Right on.  This is the actual problem.

Comment: That works, thanks. Regarding 'callable', ````callable(commands.what_time_is_it)```` returns true, so I tried the following:
````commands_list = [com for com in commands_list if (not re.match('__.+__', com) and callable('commands.' + com))]````

Which doesn't work, because ````callable('commands.' + com)```` always returns false, even though ````callable(commands.what_time_is_it)```` returns true, and ````com = what_time_is_it````.

Comment: @Alex that's because you're passing it a string, you have to pass the object like this: `callable(getattr(commands, com))`

Answer (score 4):

i would just use a list comp here:

```
commands_list = [cmd for cmd in commands_list if not (cmd.startswith('__') and cmd.endswith('__'))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), try this:

```
[item for item in my_list if '__' not in (item[:2], item[-2:])]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [item for item in my_list if '__' not in (item[:2], item[-2:])]
['datetime', 'list_commands', 'what_time_is_it']
```

The same result can be achieved using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(lambda item: '__' not in (item[:2], item[-2:]), my_list)  # list(filter(...)) for Python 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` the list:

```
commands_list = filter(lambda cmd: not re.match('__.+__', cmd), dir(commands))
```

This filters out all items that do `not` match the regex.